# Turning JSON into date object

Tags: php, angularjs, json, date

I have get request here

```
$http.get('php/getactivity.php')
    .then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.data.activities = response.data;
        },
        function (response) {
          // error handling
        }
    );
```

which gets data from database . in my php

```
<?php 
include('dbconnect.php');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Activities WHERE EventID =1;");

$outp = "";

while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {
        $outp .= ",";
    }       
    $outp .= '{"ActivityDate":"'  . $rs["ActivityDate"] . '",';     
    $outp .= '"StartTime":"'  . $rs["StartTime"] . '",';        
    $outp .= '"EndTime":"'  . $rs["EndTime"] . '"}';
}   
$outp ='['.$outp.']';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

which gets the date string from the database. An example of the data is as such :

Thu Jan 01 1970 11:11:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)

Because I'm accessing the data using `ng-repeat` and `{{ActivityDate||date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}` to make it show on the view, I cannot convert it do a date object manually using `new Date()`.

I have tried adding new date to the json produced as such but it does not work:

`$outp .= '"ActivityDate": new Date("'. $rs["ActivityDate"] . '"),';`

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: The question is "Turning JSON into date object", where is the JSON code?

Comment: Don't mash strings together to generate JSON. PHP has the `json_encode` function.

Comment: You're outputting JSON but you forgot to include `header("Content-Type: application/json");` so your PHP is going to be reporting that it is HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: you're building json manually. don't do that. ANY mistake on your part will kill the entire json block as invalid. build a php structure and then do a single `echo json_encode(...)` on it.

Comment: You can't to put Date to JSON. JSON specification has nothing for it. You should convert something like timestamps to Dates on client side.

Comment: The scary part is that you get dates out of SQL in a rather complex format : `Thu Jan 01 1970 11:11:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`. If you have proper date type columns and your database is just that smart, you should format dates explicitly to get a reproducible format. If you have dates stored as text, you have other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be simplest to format the date server-side, the way you want it displayed on the client.

One option:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rs["ActivityDate"]));
```

Here's an example of that: https://3v4l.org/6Xv03

Side note: I'd recommend you change how you generate your JSON. Build a PHP array first, and then `json_encode` it. This will avoid potential JSON format issues.

Something like:

```
$output = [];
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $output[] = [
        "ActivityDate" => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rs["ActivityDate"])),
        "StartTime" => $rs["StartTime"],
        "EndTime" => $rs["EndTime"]
    ];
}   

$conn->close();

echo(json_encode($output));
```

And then as one commenter mentioned, it helps to add a header to indicate your content type:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: is there any reason the converted date is 01/01/1970 when there is  (Malay Peninsula Standard Time) ?

Comment: Your date string is "Jan 1 1970." Regardless of the timezone, formatting that as `d/m/Y` will result in "01/01/1970". What would you expect it to be? We're not converting it to a different timezone here.

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention I used a different one with different date. https://3v4l.org/DuvX7

Comment: You can't include that parenthetical text, that makes it an invalid date string. This works: https://3v4l.org/3vRMQ

Comment: If you need to strip off the parenthetical text, here's one way to do that: https://3v4l.org/GL8V3

Comment: on my attempt to do the similar thing to time, i actually got a result 7 hours before. Expected 8am but results as 1am.  How do I convert to a different timezone?

Comment: @Lessy You may want to post a new question for that, or search for existing questions (there are a whole lot of questions about converting between timezones). More than I can easily explain in the comments.

Comment: In general: this is the point where it may now make more sense to create a `DateTime` object (rather than just the `date` function I had you use), then there are methods like http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: I don't mind being ignored every time, I have to insist on that: it's crazy to manipulate dates as free format strings. Nobody ever stores numbers in words ("twenty-four") but it's done with dates all the time. Don't fight against the tools that exist to solve your problems!

Comment: I actually took your advice and used DateTime, dint reply.  Appreciate your help.